# Issue installing SQL Server 2008 Express as a dependency via ClickOnce

Tags: windows, winforms, clickonce, sql-server-2008-express

I'm currently working on a project which has a Winforms component that is installed via ClickOnce. The original target OS was Vista and above and it continues to work fine for those platforms.

However, the customer has now requested that the application be tested against Windows XP (yes - I know it's about to have support dropped but what can I say).

When I run the installer against a fresh XP virtual machine ClickOnce duly installs the prequisites (Windows Installer 4.5 and SQL Server 2008 [with configured instance]) before installing the application itself.

Running the application appears to work as expected but when attempting to sync the local database with the remote one an exception is thrown.

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication,
>   Version 10.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies"

Now, if I start again from a clean XP VM and **Manually** install Windows Installer and SQL Server Express 2008 before starting the ClickOnce package to install the main application the resulting installation works fine and without error!

I have tried numerous things including creating a *ConfigurationFile.ini* and using that for both manual and ClickOnce installations but the result is the same - the one with the manually installation of SQL Server will run without error but the ClickOnce installation will not.

I've pretty much run out of ideas now so hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am just trying to visualize this. Is clickonce, basically, installs SSE2008 without user input? Where does it ends up installed, in internet sandbox or in program files?

Comment: It ends up in Program Files just as with a normal installation

Comment: Remember, when things run in clickOnce, they have limited access. There is possibility that some operation didn't complete, some component didn't install. May be, you should make user download and install it

Comment: The thing is - it runs fine in Windows7 with no problems whatsoever when installed via ClickOnce. The customer really wanted to be able to use the same process on XP but I think we are quickly getting to the situation where they need to ensure SQL Server is installed manually - in the same way that they will be installing the .NET Framework etc.

Comment: May be this is your situation. May be, on Win7 you already have components which for some reason, don't get installed via ClickOnce. And you think, that ClickOnce works fine on Win7. In reality, during ClickOnce these components don't install, same as on XP machine. But they already part of original WIn7 system. Try to find these components on fresh Win7, before installation.